# How to use REG_EXPAND_SZ from the commandline?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I was reading the Windows Commandline Documentation (Win+F1) about the commands that modify the Windows registry, particularly the the "reg add" command.

```
reg add HKCU\testfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v Stokrotka /d "%systemroot%\system32"
```

Now, I don't know how this was designed to work.
When I invoke the command above, the variable `%systemroot%` gets expanded to `C:\Windows`. I've tried the following not to make the variable to expand, but there is no way I could force it not to:

- escaping the `%%`'s with an `%, ^, \` - doesn't work even if I use double quotes around

  using the single quotes '' around the whole /d string

  use `setlocal setdelayedexpansion`? sth like:

`# (setlocal enabledelayedexpansion) && (reg add HKCU\testfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v Stokrotka /d "!systemroot!\system32") && (setlocal disabledelayedexpansion)`

The variable 'data' (/d) field is either like `^%systemroot^%` or like `!systemroot!` or just expands to C:\windows .
I could probably use the .reg file to accomplish my task, but I simply don't want to do it.
I thought that maybe there is something wrong with the program that I use to display the variable contents (`regedit / regedt32 / reg query (commandline)`), but after checking this is probably not the case.
Any ideas? I'm mainly interested how the variable value should look like in the regedit window, should it be like :`"%systemroot%\system32"` or `"C:\windows\system32"` to be properly expanded by other programs.
Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a command line, this worked for me:

```
reg add HKCU\testfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v Stokrotka /d ^%systemroot^%\system32
```

Comment: Thank you.  
Just to log things out.  
`reg add HKCU\testfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v Stokrotka /d ^%systemroot^%\system32`  //works  
`reg add HKCU\testfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v Stokrotka /d "^%systemroot^%\system32"`  //(notice the quotes) gives variable value: `^%systemroot^%\system32`  
Also I've found other `REG_EXPAND_SZ` in the registry and there is a `"@"` sign before `%systemroot%` (`var1=@%systemroot%\system32`). I don't know yet what `@` means, but it's probably useful.

Comment: Using `%^systemroot%\system32` or `^"%^systemroot%\system32^"` should also work; to have the quotes in the assigned value, use `\^"%^systemroot%\system32\^"` (I know this looks weird, but you have to deal with both `cmd` and `reg` and their different way of escaping (`^` and `\ `, resp.))...

Answer (score 5):

The syntax suggested by aphoria is correct, without quotes as you discovered. But you run into trouble when you need spaces in the value.

However, it *is* possible to mix-in quotes in the value. It looks weird, but it works:

`REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /d ^%SystemRoot^%;c:\Program" Files"\Intel\DMIX;C:\bin /t REG_EXPAND_SZ`

You can use quotes where needed, just not around your variables. And not right after a backslash.

Also, beware that the syntax for use in a batch file is not the same as on the command line. If you put that line into a batch file, you need to replace the "^" with another "%":

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /d %%SystemRoot%%;c:\Program" Files"\Intel\DMIX;C:\bin /t REG_EXPAND_SZ
```

(cmd.exe always reminds me of Henry Spencer's quote *"Those who do not understand Unix are condemned to reinvent it, poorly"*)

Comment: Your "replace the "^" with another "%" in the batch file" save my day! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this is an old thread, but since there doesn't seem to be an answer and I too was driven crazy by this problem, I'll share what I've come up with. It's convoluted, it's ugly, and it looks like this:

> SET VAR=% SET
>   SET VALUE=%VAR%SystemRoot%VAR%\system32...
>   REG ADD HKLM... /v Test /t
>   REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %VALUE%

I end up with Test containing the string `%SystemRoot%\system32`

Edit: Should have finished testing before posting. While this worked from the command line, it failed in my command scripts. What DID work was `SET VALUE=%%SystemRoot%%\system32...`

Answer (score 1):

We have a use in an autounattend.xml.  I was first following aphoria's answer, then I had to use mivk's enhanced answer.  I had it working.  Then I made a small change and it stopped working.  I consider this insight worth reporting, to save others lengthy frustration.

Building on previous answers, here is how to make this work in autounattend.xml:

```
<CommandLine>cmd.exe /c reg.exe add HKLM\ourkey /v ourvalue /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "our data with spaces"^%USERNAME^%"and more spaces" /f</CommandLine>
```

What matters is the cmd.exe /c.  If you don't use cmd.exe then reg.exe still runs, but it puts literally ^% into the registry, not the desired %.

Maybe the answer by ASTX813 would work, but this seems easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic here, you must escape every % in command-line with/become: %%.

In batch file, you again must escape them, become %%%%SystemRoot%%%%. Yes, four ampersands. It's ugly, but it's the way it is, and it's pretty consistent though.

note: Using ^ to escape it as literal character might help/cleanup in one step/degree only (as long as it's not interpreted). The advantage using ^ is that you can write in command-line or batch file with identical syntax: eg. "^%SytemRoot^%", since in both environments, % treated equally as literal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple.  Only quote the spaces and escape the %'s.

In command line, escape the %'s with the ^.

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command" "Processor /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d title" "^%username^% /f
```

In batch file, escape the %'s with another %.

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command" "Processor /v AutoRun  /t REG_SZ /d title" "%%username%% /f
```

This took me a while to figure out.  In my mind, I should quote the entire string, but could not get the variable to be passed without expanding it.  I broke my way of thinking by quoting spaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

reg add HKCU\testfolder /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v Stokrotka /d ^%systemroot%^\system32

Answer (score 0):

From a batch file you end up with problems with quotes, which you can then escape with a backslash, for example:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\%name%" /v "UninstallString" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"%%comspec%%\" /d /c \"%dest%\uninstall.cmd\""
```

Answer (score 0):

without quotes

```
reg add HKCU\testfolder /v Biedronka /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%%^%systemroot%%%^%\system32"
```

with quotes

```
reg add HKCU\testfolder /v Biedronka /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%%systemroot^%%\system32\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got sick of the banner/logo on CScript and decided to prefix VBS associations with `//nologo` in my 'new build' batch script. This required modifying a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry entry with an environment variable and this question and its various answers were the best inspiration I could find. Here's the final script.

```
SET "thecmd=\""%%SystemRoot%%\System32\CScript.exe\"" //nologo \""%%1\"" %%*"
ECHO.%thecmd%
REG.exe ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%thecmd%" /f
SET thecmd=
```

Storing the command in a variable and using `\""` for `"` and `%%` for `%` are what allows it to work.

If you prefer a one-liner (again, from batch) you can use:

```
REG.exe ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\""%%SystemRoot%%\System32\CScript.exe\"" //nologo \""%%1\"" %%*" /f
```

If you want the same functionality, don't forget to set the verb for `VBSFile` to `Open2` so you can just double-click VBS files to run them with CScript:

```
REG.exe ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Open2" /f
```