# Using uri scheme with %APPDATA%

Tags: batch-file, uri

My .reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest]
@="URL:cultest Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\DefaultIcon]
@="%APPDATA%\\musicDownloader\\test.bat,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open\command]
@="%APPDATA%\\musicDownloader\\test.bat \"%1\""
```

Using cultest://something doesn't work. But IF I replaced %APPDATA% with static path It worked.

Comment: What do you mean under "doesn't work"?

Comment: nothing happen in Chrome, "wrong path" in Edge.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

> Just use REG_EXPAND_SZ instead of REG_SZ when you want to embed
>   environment variables in the registry key value.

[Using windows environment variables as registry values in Visual Studio Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101870/using-windows-environment-variables-as-registry-values-in-visual-studio-installe)